# ¿Cómo validar un datagridview para que acepte sólo teclas numéricas?

Tags: c#

estoy creando un proyecto con ecuaciones diferenciales y necesito capturar datos en un `datagrid` y que sólo acepte valores numéricos en las celdas, creo las celdas desde el código y el código en `keypress` no me funciona

```
        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podrias asignar el evento `KeyPress` a la celda para impedir se ingrese un caracter que no sea numerico, para poder hacerlo debes obtener el textbox usando el evento `EditingControlShowing` y adjuntando el evento

```
public void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;

    dText.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dText_KeyPress); 
    dText.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dText_KeyPress);
}

void dText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me haz salvado la vida jaja XD

Comment: Está bueno este método, pero si quisiera que incluyera dos decimales, ¿cómo le debería modificar?