# Evitar que introduzcan letras en el datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo una pequeña duda que la indico a continuación , como puedo evitar que en el datagrid no sean ingresadas letras como se ve en la imagen que adjunto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realice el evento de validación del keypress para el datagrid como se ve en el código que muestro a continuación.

```
private void dataGridHoras_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Solo se Permite el Ingreso de Numeros", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Pero como se ve en la imagen adjuntada no me funciona, en que otro evento tengo implementar ese código para que funcione.

De antemano les agradezco la atención prestada.

Saludos.

Comment: primero tienes que obtener el numero de columna con e.ColumnIndex == 1 o el numero que queiras para numeros y despues tu metodo.

Comment: Me podrías dar una guía de como poder implementarlo correctamente @Manny por favor.

Comment: Tu pregunta quizas esta duplicada y esto de pueda ayudar, aca el companero @Leandro dio una solucion https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10565/c%C3%B3mo-validar-un-datagridview-para-que-acepte-s%C3%B3lo-teclas-num%C3%A9ricas/10572

Comment: Si efectivamente es lo que estabas buscando , te agradezco por tu ayuda.